# SQL concat() function issue when creating Views

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a view to concatenate two numbers but I cannot use the `concat()` function. Although when i use `@number1+ - +@number2` it adds two numbers.

Please help.

Comment: + is a sql server concat shortcut that does not exist in mysql where + is a arithmetic operator.

Comment: You cannot use user defined variables in a view - if you want to merge to columns that's fine , I don't get why you are attempting to use user defined variables.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  `concat()` works on numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat()` on numbers:

```
select concat(@number1, '-', @number2)
```

Comment: Using Concat does not enable me to create a view.

Comment: I think the error message is quite clear when you attempt to create a view using variables. It might help if you expanded on what you want the view to do.

Comment: I just want to merge two columns to be able to perform a join later.